# Discharging 2 capacitors in synchronized manner in a resistor

Tags: capacitor, discharge

Let suppose a single capacitor when discharged through a resistor via switch gives you "x" current.
Now if I attach another set of switch and capacitor across that resistor and turn on both the switches simultaneously, will the current flowing through the resistor get doubled?

Comment: Simple mathematics. Two capacitors in parallel, summarize capacitance. Now you can calculate the current. What is the question about?

Comment: Why would it? How is this different from connecting the two capacitors in parallel and running them through the same switch? It'll just take longer for the capacitor voltage to drop.

Comment: Ohm's Law says the current through the resistor will only depend on the applied voltage.  If adding a second capacitor with the same voltage as the first capacitor, will the voltage across the resistor change?

Comment: Thanks alot everyone for answering. I was thinking the same. Just posted to get it cleared.

Comment: If the two capacitors are at different voltages, the high one will charge the low one until they are equal, with possible side entertainment (sparks).  After which, the total charge will dissipate through the resistor.

Comment: the discharging through the resistor begins immediately ... there is no pause until capacitors are equalized

Comment: I have added a sketch in the question, can you all re-comment on that ?

Comment: You edited your question and added a schematic. However, this showed series inductors in the circuit. These were not part of your original question and suddenly adding them disrupts the work put into existing answers and comments. Accordingly, I've rolled back the question. If you have a new question on inductors in a similar circuit, please post that as a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You describe the two circuits below and ask about the right-hand circuit.

The answer is: it depends on the voltages that C2 and C3 are each charged to.

---

Let's consider `Vc1` = `Vc2` = `Vc3`. When S2&S3 are closed, C2 and C3 act like one big capacitor with the same charged voltage. So R2 current `Ir2` is the same for both circuits, at `Vc2/R2` (or `Vc3/R2`). Bigger capacitance C2&C3 takes longer to discharge through R2.

---

Now consider `Vc2` <> `Vc3`. When S2&S3 are closed, the higher voltage capacitor, be it C2 or C3, discharges relatively quickly into the other capacitor, at a current limited only by their ESRs and the connecting resistances. The voltage at the node for R2 will cause an R2 current `Ir2` of `Vnode/R2`.

Shortly after, the capacitance voltages will have equalised as far as the discharging through R2 allows them to. A high R2 value won't interfere with the voltages equalising, while a low R2 value will.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTa3tS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What if we add an inductor to both legs adjacent to each capacitor ?

Comment: I have added a sketch in the question statement. Can you comment on that?